# How to show that randperm() in matlab is fair

Tags: matlab, probability, combinatorics

Suppose, I wanted to show (empirically) that randperm(n,k) from matlab indeed produces uniformly distributed random samples of size k from a set N of n elements. How can I plot the number of occurences divided by the total number of k-subsets drawn from N, after drawing repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the indices drawn from `randperm` to increment a counter vector.

```
n=1e5;
k=1e4;
maxiter = 1e5;

% This array will be used to count the number of times each integer has been drawn
count=zeros(n,1);

for ii=1:maxiter
    p=randperm(n,k);
    % p is a vector of k distinct integers in the 1:n range
    % the array count will be incremented at indices given by p
    count(p)=count(p)+1;
end

% A total of k*maxiter integers has been drawn and they should be evenly
% distributed over n values
% The following vector should have values close to 1 for large values of maxiter
prob = count*n/(k*maxiter);
```